# T-SQL Dynamic variable insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

can some one help, with this query. I have 10 rows in my temp table

```
Declare @date date = '2014-11-01'
Declare @iDate int = '20141101'
Create table #test33(Paname  varchar(100))
insert into #test33

Go
```

Now i have 10 rows in temp table. I want to insert those temp values in my cte dynamically

```
Declare @StartDate date = '2014-11-01'
Declare @EndDate date = '2014-11-30'
Declare @Paname   nvarchar(100) = 'MPU' --- i have  multiple panames how can i insert dyamically in cte or any other solution?



 ;with pla as
          (     SELECT*
          FROM  [dbo].[Pla] pl
                 JOIN dbo.testplan cl
                 ON pl.ClientId = cl.ClientId
                 where  pl.name = @Paname  
                 and pl.StartDate >= @StartDate and pl.EndDate <= @EndDate
                 ) 
   select * from pla
```

Comment: you don't "insert" data on a CTE. I'm having issues understanding what you actually want here

Comment: What's the deal with the first block of code?  You're creating a temp table and then trying to select into the temp table data from the just created temp table?  How does the first block in any way relate to the second block?

Comment: Hi Lamak, I have 10 Paname rows in my temp table, instead of 10 time have to enter paname in cte variable to get my results, can i get results dynamically to insert one after the other ?

Comment: Hi Kritner, first block in nutshell i just gave e.g. that i have some row in temp table, which i want to insert dynamically in to variable in second block of code and that variable name is Paname Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can loop throw multiple parameters using WHILE or using CURSOR. Inside it you can used dynamic sql:

```
declare @DSQL varchar(MAX)

SET @DSQL = ';with pla as
            (     SELECT*
                  FROM  [dbo].[Pla] pl
                  JOIN dbo.testplan cl
                  ON pl.ClientId = cl.ClientId
                  where  pl.name = '+@Paname+' 
                  and pl.StartDate >= '+@StartDate+' and pl.EndDate <= '+@EndDate+'
                  ) 
               select * from pla'
EXEC(@DSQL)
```